# Need help to write jQuery code correctly

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-web-api2

I'm writing an instant messaging module for my application, using jQuery on client side. Everything works fine, just have one problem how to write correct one part of code.
Here is part of code,  that displays messages at UI:

```
function messageBuildTableRow(message) {
    var pm =
    "<li>" +
        "<div class='alert alert-warning'>" +
            "<p>" + message.Body + "<span> - </span>" + moment(message.SentAt).calendar() + "</p>" +
        "</div>" +
    "</li>";
    return pm;
}
```

But I want to make senders message different style, so my solution is like this:

```
function messageBuildTableRow(message) {
    var pm =
        "<li>" +
            if(message.SenderUserName == @User.Identity.Name) {
                "<div class='alert alert-info'>" +
            } else {
                "<div class='alert alert-warning'>" +
            }
                    "<p>" +message.Body + "<span> - </span>" + moment(message.SentAt).calendar() + "</p>" +
                "</div>" +
         "</li>";
    return pm;
}
```

I'm getting syntax error can someone help write this part of code correctly.

Comment: What is a sithax error?

Comment: I think OP means 'syntax'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@User.Identity.Name` outputs a string value. You need to wrap that output in quotes so when it's written to the page JS will also recognise it as a string. Try this:

```
if (message.SenderUserName == '@User.Identity.Name')
{
    // your code...
}
```

Also note that you cannot directly append an `if` condition. You need to separate your statements:

```
function messageBuildTableRow(message) {
    var pm = "<li>";

    if (message.SenderUserName == '@User.Identity.Name') {
        pm += "<div class='alert alert-info'>";
    } else {
        pm += "<div class='alert alert-warning'>"
    }

    pm += "<p>" + message.Body + "<span> - </span>" + moment(message.SentAt).calendar() + "</p></div></li>";

    return pm;
}
```

This can be shortened further using a ternary:

```
function messageBuildTableRow(message) {
    return '<li><div class="alert ' + (message.SenderUserName == '@User.Identity.Name' ? 'alert-info' : 'alert-warning') +  '"><p>' + message.Body + '<span> - </span>' + moment(message.SentAt).calendar() + '</p></div></li>';
}
```

Comment: Lot of thanks! this code worked for me function messageBuildTableRow(message) {
    var pm = "<li>";

    if (message.SenderUserName == '@User.Identity.Name') {
        pm += "<div class='alert alert-info'>";
    } else {
        pm += "<div class='alert alert-warning'>"
    }

    pm += "<p>" + message.Body + "<span> - </span>" + moment(message.SentAt).calendar() + "</p></div></li>";

    return pm;
}

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that this piece of code written is in `.cshtml` page rather than in a separate `js` page, you could try it as below:

```
function messageBuildTableRow(message) {
    var diffElement=message.SenderUserName == @User.Identity.Name?
                    "<div class='alert alert-info'>":
                    "<div class='alert alert-warning'>";
    //Instead of if, have a ternary operator and store the necessary alert type in a variable

    //add it directly then as below
    var pm ="<li>" + diffElement +

    "<p>" +message.Body + "<span> - </span>" + moment(message.SentAt).calendar() +
    "</p>" +
    "</div>" +
    "</li>";
    return pm;
}
```